# SVN: Committing Changes Made to Trunk to a Branch

Tags: svn, branch, commit, trunk

I have made a checkout from Trunk, made changes and committed the changes back to the trunk.  Now, I want apply those changes to a branch as well.  Can I switch my working copy to that branch and then commit those files that have changed to the branch?  I do have the list of the files that I have changed, and thus I know which files to commit.  But I want to see if switching my local copy to that branch is the way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to [merge](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html#svn.branchemerge.basicmerging.stayinsync) your trunk changes into the branch.

This is a *very* common use case and I urge you to read the whole chapter in the SVN manual regarding branching and merging so you understand what you need to do here and why.

Comment: The project is a huge project.  So, there are many contributors.  Is it easy to limit the merge to only those files that I have changed?  I certainly don't want to merge the whole trunk to the branch since there has been many changes by others to both trunk and branch.

Comment: Yes, you can. Get the revisions you want to merge, and [cherrypick them](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.cherrypicking) when issuing the merge command.

Comment: You can cherry-pick, but how will you know if your changes are compatible with everyone else's before you merge back to the trunk?

Comment: @alroc I'm not sure I follow. Regardless of whether one cherrypicks revisions or merges a whole range of revisions, there is always a chance that the changes made in the branch post-merge (#1) will be incompatible with the changes everyone else has made in trunk - which should become evident when merging that branch back into trunk (merge #2). Care to explain what you mean?

Comment: @SameerSingh the longer you wait to merge with everyone else's work, the greater the chances for breakage (and more significant breakage) when you finally do merge with them.

Comment: @alroc Surely that's true regardless of whether you cherrypick-merge or not?

Comment: If you cherry-pick, you're delaying the merge of other changes. If you don't, you'll merge those changes earlier. I'm not saying you need to do the full merge *every* time, but waiting a few weeks or longer on a changing codebase will make it harder.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your branch was made off of trunk (or a branch off of trunk), you can merge the changes up into your branch. [More info here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html).